# Python regex pattern max length in re.compile?

Tags: python, regex, maxlength

I try to compile a big pattern with `re.compile` in Python 3.

The pattern I try to compile is composed of 500 small words (I want to remove them from a text). The problem is that it stops the pattern after about 18 words

Python doesn't raise any error.

What I do is:

```
stoplist = map(lambda s: "\\b" + s + "\\b", stoplist)
stopstring = '|'.join(stoplist)
stopword_pattern = re.compile(stopstring)
```

The stopstring is ok (all the words are in) but the pattern is much shorter. It even stops in the middle of a word!

Is there a max length for the regex pattern?

Comment: Could you post a full working example program? This is impossible to reproduce right now.

Comment: I think you're confusing the string representation of `stopword_pattern` with the pattern it actually stores internally.

Comment: making an alternation with 500 items is a very bad idea.

Comment: Thank you, in fact there were a non escaped character after the representation of the stopwordpattern (bad luck!). So I advice, in this case (construction of a pattern) always to use the re.escape fonction...
However, @CasimiretHippolyte, I'd like to know what kind of alternative you would use. Maybe something simple but less flexible like `if word in stoplist`? Why making an alternation of hundreds of elements is a bad idea?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte why? Could you please explain the reason?

Comment: @Grief: Take a 50 words string *(a small string, less than the previous comment size)*, so 100 word-boundaries *(start and end of each word)*. You have 500 words in the stoplist, this means that there are in the best scenario about 20 stopwords that starts with the same letter for each letter *(this means that the pattern will fail after the second or third letter)*. In the worst case (no stopword in the string), the regex engine performs 500x50=25000 tests for all ends of words, and at least 500x2.5x50=62500 *(probably more)* for all starts of words before failing.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Sorry, but this is not how regex engine works. There is a finite-state machine under the hood. Your calculations are far from the truth. In case when no one of 'stop words' contains special characters like `?` or `*`, there will be only 50 comparisons, one for each letter.

Comment: @Grief: you seems confuse, to illustrate my explanation, take a look at this example (for 25 words), try to add more words to see how the number of steps needed is growing: https://regex101.com/r/gC6oH0/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte what do you mean by 'steps'? Why did you paste this link? Steps of the state machine are not displayed there. Compilation will take some time, but the search itself is performed in the most efficient way and will not require so many comparisons as you said.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you can look how state machine looks like here: http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa, try to generate NFA and DFA for `word1|word2|other|another`, for example.

Comment: @Grief: The Python re module doesn't work the way you think. Most of the regex engines used in modern languages (Perl, Python, PHP, Java...) don't generate a DFA. The main reasons are to offer a better control of the way the regex engine will search the string, to reduce the compilation time and to provide features that are impossible (or don't make sense) with a DFA regex engine (backreferences, atomic grouping, non-greedy quantifiers, backtracking...). The counter part of this choice is that these engines work in a more silly way and the search is slower in some situations.

Comment: @Grief: In particular they don't work in parallel. Some of them to speed up the research have an optimization phase before the *normal walk* of the engine (ie:character by character for the string, token by token for the pattern) called "transmission" by J.Friedl, where for instance positions of literal strings of the pattern are searched with a fast algorithm in the string before, but it isn't always possible and I doubt that the re module has many of these features. However, regex engines that produce a DFA always exists and are used with lex, MySQL, egrep...

Comment: @Grief: and if you want you can install a module called re2 that provides a DFA regex engine. In general beware to the terms used in practice and in computer science, since many of them are language abuse (for example *regular expression*).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks. I've looked throw both CPython's 'Secret Labs Regular Expression Engine` and Java's Pattern implementation and it seems that everything you said is correct. I was confused by the documentation for java's Pattern ("The Pattern engine performs traditional NFA-based matching with ordered alternation as occurs in Perl 5"), but in fact it's hugely modified NFA. Thanks for finding the time for exaplanations. Cheers!

Comment: @Grief: Yes, as you can see the term *NFA* can also be source of confusion.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I just realized about which steps you were talking about: there is a number of steps above modifiers input. Didn't notice it.

Answer (score 11):

Consider this example:

```py
import re
stop_list = map(lambda s: "\\b" + str(s) + "\\b", range(1000, 2000))
stop_string = "|".join(stop_list)
stop_word_pattern = re.compile(stop_string)
```

If you try to print the pattern, you'll see something like:

```
>>> print(stop_word_pattern)
re.compile('\\b1000\\b|\\b1001\\b|\\b1002\\b|\\b1003\\b|\\b1004\\b|\\b1005\\b|\\b1006\\b|\\b1007\\b|\\b1008\\b|\\b1009\\b|\\b1010\\b|\\b1011\\b|\\b1012\\b|\\b1013\\b|\\b1014\\b|\\b1015\\b|\\b1016\\b|\\b1017\\b|\)
```

which seems to indicate that the pattern is incomplete. However, this just seems to be a limitation of the `__repr__` and/or `__str__` methods for `re.compile` objects. If you try to perform a match against the "missing" part of the pattern, you'll see that it still succeeds:

```
>>> stopword_pattern.match("1999")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0,4), match='1999')
```

As explained in the comments, you can return a complete pattern with `.pattern`, e.g.:

```py
stopword_pattern.pattern
```

Comment: `stopword_pattern.pattern` should contain the complete string he's looking for.  (This is in Python 2.6 and 3.1, where compiled regexes don't appear to have custom `__str__` or `__repr__` methods.  It may have changed since then.)

Comment: Good to know. The above was tested in 3.4; I can confirm that in 2.6, at least, `object.__repr__` is used to output a generic instance string.